# Django test without vpn

Tags: python, django, testing

I want to test my function, where I add a new object to a database and then (still in this function) the object is being sent to a server. The problem is that to send the object to a server I need to run VPN. I'm wondering is there a way to run this function in my test, but skip the line responsible for sending the object to the server, or somehow simulate this behavior? Currently, I'm not able to run my test because  I'm getting `Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out`

My test looks like this:

```
    def test_create_ticket_POST_adds_new_ticket(self):
        response = self.client.post(self.create_ticket_url, {
            'title': 'test title',
            'description': 'test description',
            'grant_id': 'test grant id',
        })
        result_title = Ticket.objects.filter(owner=self.user).order_by('-last_update').first().title
        result_count = Ticket.objects.filter(owner=self.user).count()

        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertEquals(result_title, 'test title')
        self.assertEquals(result_count, 1)
```

And the post request is calling this function:

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def create_ticket(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ticket_form = TicketForm(request.POST)
        tags_form = TagsForm(request.POST)
        attachments = AttachmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if ticket_form.is_valid() and attachments.is_valid() and tags_form.is_valid():
            jira = JIRA(server=JIRA_URL, basic_auth=(jira_user, jira_password))
            new_issue = add_issue(request, jira, ticket_form)
            add_attachments(request, jira, new_issue)
            set_tags(request, new_issue, tags_form)

            messages.info(request, _(f"Ticket {new_issue} has been created."))
            return redirect(f'/tickets/{new_issue}/')
    else:
        ticket_form = TicketForm()
        tags_form = TagsForm()
        attachments = AttachmentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    return render(request, "client_interface/ticketform.html",
                  {'ticket_form': ticket_form, 'attachments': attachments, 'tags_form': tags_form})
```

And this is all about `JIRA_URL` in my view function.

Comment: You need just to mock that server call. You can read more about that https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html
So the main idea is that during the test the flow won't call the function you mock, but return what you set to be returned instead.

Comment: Could you please describe this process a bit more precisely? I understand the idea, but I'm not calling the JIRA function in my test directly, it's nested in my view function. I'm just still not sure how can I write my mock JIRA function in my tests file, so it will be called in my `create_ticket` function instead of the real JIRA function.

Comment: This is the case, you add mock in your test where you "say" that when you meet that function do not call it, but return me what I say instead of calling it. That's it. Please read that article carefully. There are examples in the end so you will understand.

Comment: Finally I managed to do it, thank you for the link, it was extremely helpful.